# Given the derivative of $f(x)$, find all possible values of $a$ which is an unknown in the cubic equation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Consider the function $f$, with a derivative 
>   $$f'(x)=2x^2+5ax+3a^2+2$$ where $x, a \in \mathbb{R}$. Given that $f$ is an increasing function, find all possible values of $a$.

That is the question. I've tried finding the function from the derivative but can't seem to workout the possible values of $a$.

Comment: Hint: You are given the derivative of a function. Would the fact that a function is **strinctly increasing** have anything to do with the derivative? Don't worry about the original function, only the derivative.

Comment: I've given a potentially better answer; please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $f$ is an increasing function, this implies $\forall x\in\Bbb R, f'\geq0$.  Therefore we want $f'$ to be non-negative.

A quadratic function is non-negative if its leading coefficient is positive and its discriminant $\Delta\leq0$.  Therefore, we have
\begin{align}
\Delta&\leq0\\
(5a)^2-4(2)(3a^2+2)&\leq0\\
25a^2-24a^2-16&\leq0\\
a^2&\leq16\\
|a|&\leq4.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is increasing, hence $f' \ge 0$ on $ \mathbb R.$ Thus the quadratic equation

$$2x^2+5ax+3a^2+2=0$$

has only one solution.

Show that this is the case $ \iff a^2=16.$

Comment: $f'$ can be non-negative also if it has no real roots.  Please see my answer.

Comment: The OP should care about Andrew's remark.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+\frac52ax+\frac32a^2+1=\left(x+\frac54a\right)^2-\frac1{16}a^2+1.$$

This is non-negative when $a^2\le16$.